# Is there an Eigen C++ library equivalent to gsl_multifit_wlinear()?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen, gsl

I'm trying to port some older GSL code to using the header only Eigen library.  I'm doing this as a side job for some data scientists and as such my math has lapsed a little since college.  I'm trying to see if there's an equivalent function or module or even a more general linear algebra term for the gsl_multifit_wlinear() function call.  It looks like a least-squares curve fitting function.

If there is a way of directly converting that, what would it be?

If not, is there another library I can use?  Keep in mind here that it must not have a GPL or similar "share all code" license.  MIT or BSD is preferred, LGPL and Mozilla/Apache are ok too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `gsl_multifit_linear(X,y,c)` solves the problem `min_c ||Xc-y||^2`. I'm actually not 100% sure from the documentation but it looks like `gsl_multifit_wlinear(X,y,w,c)` solves `min_c ||Xc - y||^2_W` where `W = diag(w)` and `||e||^2_W = e'*W^(-1)*e`.

So, you can solve this in Eigen by rewriting `min_c ||Xc - y||^2_W` as `min_c ||W^(-1/2) (Xc - y)||^2`.

We have to:

- compute W^(-1/2), which is just diagonal with elements W(i,i) = 1/sqrt(w(i)).
- Compute A = W^(-1/2)*X and b = W^(-1/2)*y
- Solve `min ||Ac - b||^2`, which is the same as solving `Ac = b` in a least squares sense

This should work then, assuming you already have Eigen::Matrix<...> of X, y, w:

```
Eigen::VectorXd inv_sqrtw = 1.0 / w.array().sqrt();
Eigen::MatrixXd W12 = inv_sqrtw.asDiagonal();
Eigen::MatrixXd A = W12 * X;
Eigen::VectorXd b = W12 * y;

// now solve system
Eigen::VectorXd c = A.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(b);
```

and your answer is in `c`

More info about solving least squares problem in Eigen is at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__LeastSquares.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the math update.  I will try this and see if it works and will accept at that point.

Comment: for sure, let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Seems to be working as proposed, accepted.  Thanks Sean